# How to skip String index out of range and Program stil running

Tags: java

my code is read file and check input name match data in file . if it match then print it

i use method substring to check match them. I know error wil appear at line 1 in file because line 1 have only 4 character , so 4<12 then will got error.

So how to skip that error and program still continue running ? My mean is assuming 4 is less than 12 then ignore ,then it read next line until read all line , if match will print it and program end.

Thank you and sorry my bad english

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
String ss,sss;File file =new File("cauthu.dat");
        ss=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "input name");
        FileReader fr;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
            try {
                while((sss=br.readLine())!=null)
                {sss.substring(12);int l=sss.length();System.out.println(l);}
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Form7.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

`
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Form7.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

this is data in file:

```
Id:1
name:hello
Nam sinh:2000
Vi tri:thu mon
--------------------------
Id:2
name:hi
Nam sinh:2000
Vi tri:tien dao
--------------------------
Id:3
name:hello hi
Nam sinh:2000
Vi tri:tien dao
--------------------------
```

this is error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -8
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
    at bai7.Form7.findActionPerformed(Form7.java:195)
    at bai7.Form7.access$100(Form7.java:23)
    at bai7.Form7$2.actionPerformed(Form7.java:73)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper$6.dispatchEvent(AtkWrapper.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Rather than skip the error, why not just check the length of `sss` ? `if (sss.length() > 12)`

Comment: hi, i tried but cannot check , it still got that error

Comment: _String index out of range: -8_ How do you get -8 for the string index?

Comment: "hi, i tried but cannot check , it still got that error" - please show us what you tried. It's not clear why you're calling `substring` at all given that you're ignoring the result.

Comment: (I'd also strongly encourage you to lay out your source code more conventionally, *at least* for Stack Overflow - conventionally I'd expect to see a single line per statement, rather than your current "whole loop body in one line with no whitespace other than what's strictly required.)

Comment: Rather than use `substring()` use `sss.equals(ss)` (or `sss.contains(ss)` depending on your need). That will avoid the error, but you have bigger problems. First read the lines and from them create an instance of a suitable class. Then do your test on it.

Comment: @CatDragon - Any update?

Comment: @Bohemian oh thank you , i tried with contains and it work . i do not known about contains() . thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you are getting `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` by using `String#substring`, you should put `sss.substring(12)` inside a `try-catch` block and since you want to simply ignore the error, do not put any code inside the `catch` block.
2. You should also ensure to close the resources. A good way to do it is by using the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

**Demo:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String ss, sss;
        ss = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "input name");
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("cauthu.dat"))) {
            while ((sss = br.readLine()) != null) {
                try {
                    sss.substring(12);
                    int l = sss.length();
                    System.out.println(l);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
13
14
26
13
15
26
13
13
15
26
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `substring()` use `sss.contains(ss)`, which will avoid the error.

---

You could improve the readability of your code by first reading 4 lines and from them create an instance of a suitable class. Then do your tests etc with that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `Scanner` and retrieve found data in the file reading each section step-by-step? You can avoid `string split` but using `Scanner` with custom delimiter.

```
public static Map<Integer, Data> readDataFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Map<Integer, Data> map = new HashMap<>();

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        scan.useDelimiter("[\n:]");

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            scan.next();    // skip 'Id'
            int id = scan.nextInt();
            scan.next();    // sile 'name'
            String name = scan.next();
            scan.next();    // sile 'Nam sinh'
            int nameSinh = scan.nextInt();
            scan.next();    // sile 'Vi tri'
            String viTri = scan.next();

            if (map.put(id, new Data(id, name, nameSinh, viTri)) != null)
                throw new RuntimeException("'Id' duplication");

            scan.nextLine();
            scan.nextLine();    // skip '----'
        }
    }

    return map;
}

public final class Data {

    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final int nameSinh;
    private final String viTri;

    public Data(int id, String name, int nameSinh, String viTri) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.nameSinh = nameSinh;
        this.viTri = viTri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey may be you catch the exception if you want to skip to it here is what can be done

```
public static void main(String []argh){
     String ss,sss;
     File file =new File("C:\\Users\\nishant.kumar\\Desktop\\input.dat");
     FileReader fr;
     try {
         fr = new FileReader(file);
         BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
         try {
             while((sss=br.readLine())!=null)
             {
                 try {
                     sss.substring(12);
                     int l=sss.length();
                     System.out.println(l);
                 }
                 catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                     //System.out.println("Caught Exception");
                     continue;
                 }
             }
         } catch (IOException ex) {

         }
     } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

     }
 }
```

Hope this works.

Comment: I would really discourage this approach - avoiding the problem entirely is better IMO than catching the exception.

Answer (score -1):

Hey but this is working..

```
public static void main(String []argh){
     String ss,sss;
     File file =new File("C:\\Users\\nishant.kumar\\Desktop\\input.dat");
     FileReader fr;
     try {
         fr = new FileReader(file);
         BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
         try {
             while((sss=br.readLine())!=null)
             {
                 if(sss.length()>12) {
                     sss.substring(12);
                     int l=sss.length();
                     System.out.println(l);                      
                 }
             }
         } catch (IOException ex) {

         }
     } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

     }
 }
```

Comment: The `sss.substring(12)` call in your code is pointless, as you ignore the result.